# Disabling user secrets in asp.net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

So, I have this setup in my project which makes my launchSettings.json file look like this:

```
"profiles": {
  "LeadDog.Web - Local": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"
    }
  },
  "LeadDog.Web - Dev": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  }
}
```

This is so that we can test things with the Dev database from our local computers should we need to. But because we are also using User Secrets, those take precedence over the actual appsettings.Development.json file which make it so that the only way to get the values from the config file is to disable user secrets in the project.

Is there a way to disable user secrets based on an environment variable?

Edit:

I'll be more specific: I want to use user secrets only in a custom environment called "Local", the default of *CreateDefaultBuilder* is to allow it in the "Develoment" environment. Is there a way to do this while still using CreateDefaultBuilder?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why you have the same information in secret and settings? Delete information from secrets of your computer.

Comment: Did that, but then the application crashes during runtime because it doesn't find a valid JSON in the secrets.json file.

Comment: You can't disable the user secrets at the runtime. If you want to get the secret data based on the environment variable, you could use the [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0) in your application `var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");`. More detailed information, refer to [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: I don't want to disable user secrets during runtime... I want to register it in my custom "Local" environment rather than the "Development" one. I want to change the basic configuration that _CreateDefaultBuilder_ uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure how it's a problem; the contents of user secrets is *typically* patched over the other appsettings files (The config is the result of the union of config files with a "user secrets wins" strategy) so all you need to do is empty your user secrets file - make it `{}` and put all your config in appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json - these files are also merged (appsettings.Development wins over appsettings) so you put config items you want to apply to both production and dev in appsettings, and you put items that are dev only (test database connection string perhaps) into appsettings.Development.json

For more detailed info on how config works you can [see MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configuration-providers)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I was removing everything from the file, so when it tried to parse the JSON it was crashing the application. Still, what I am looking for it to override the default way user secrets are handled, have them be used only in the "Local" environment and not in the "Development" environment. Is it possible to do this while using _CreateDefaultBuilder_?

Comment: Updated the question to clarify similarly to this comment.